# Búsqueda binaria en java

Tags: java, busqueda

Espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema estoy realizando un programa de búsqueda binaria en un arreglo donde el usuario define el tamaño y el llenado del arreglo además del número que desea buscar el problema es que si por ejemplo ingresa los siguientes números: 1,2,3 y el quiere buscar el 4, yo necesito que le arroje que el número no se encuentra en el arreglo pero no sé como hacerlo. Les dejo lo que llevo del código:

```
public class BusquedaBinaria {

    int busquedaBinaria(int A[], int x, int i, int j) {

        int medio;
        if (i > j) {
            return 0;
        }
        medio = (i + j) / 2;
        if (A[medio] < x) {
            return busquedaBinaria(A, x, medio + 1, j);
        } else if (A[medio] > x) {
            return busquedaBinaria(A, x, i, medio - 1);
        } else {
            return medio + 1;
        }
    }
}

public class PruebaBusquedaBinaria {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BusquedaBinaria f = new BusquedaBinaria();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo:");
        n=scan.nextInt();
        int A[]= new int[n];
        int s;
        System.out.println("Ingrese los numero para llenar el arreglo:");
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            A[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("EL arreglo sin ordenar es:");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(A[i]+" ");   
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Los datos ordenados son: ");
        Arrays.sort(A);
        for (int i = 0; i <n; i++) {
            System.out.print(A[i]+" "); 
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        System.out.println("ingrese el numero que desea buscar");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
      if(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n)>=n){
          System.out.println("El numero no se encontro");
      }else{
          System.out.println("La posicion del numero fue: ");
          System.out.println(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n));
      }
    }   
}
```

lo que yo estaba intentando era hacer el siguiente if(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n)>=n) pero no me funciono.

Comment: En que momento, busqueda binaria devuelve el valor si lo encontro? eso es lo que falla.

Comment: entonces tendria que poner un return -1? o que me recomiendas hacer

Comment: usa nombres de variables que sirvan para algo (x, j, i no significan nada). en que momento, en tu codigo, te estas fijando si el valor que buscas es el mismo donde estas parado en la lista?

Comment: pues esta parte se encarga de hacer el analisis

Comment: int medio;
        if (i > j) {
            return 0;
        }
        medio = (i + j) / 2;
        if (A[medio] < x) {
            return busquedaBinaria(A, x, medio + 1, j);
        } else if (A[medio] > x) {
            return busquedaBinaria(A, x, i, medio - 1);
        } else {
            return medio + 1;
        }
    }
}

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. Como sabes si el elemento lo encontraste o no? que linea te dice eso?

Answer (score 0):

A la hora de detenerse en tu `busquedaBinaria()` en el caso de que no lo encuentra (el limite inferior es mas grande que el superior)

```
if (i > j) {
   return 0;
}
```

Estas devolviendo 0, la cual es la primer posicion del arreglo. Tendrias que devolver una posicion que no existe por ejemplo -1, luego a la hora de controlar que el elemento se encuentra en el arreglo te cercioras de que sea distinto a -1.
En cuanto a esta sección de codigo:

```
  if(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n)>=n){
      System.out.println("El numero no se encontro");
  }else{
      System.out.println("La posicion del numero fue: ");
      System.out.println(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n));
  }
```

Seria mas eficiente realizar la busqueda binaria y guardar el resultado en una variable:

```
int resultado = f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n);
if(f.busquedaBinaria(A, x, 0, n) != -1){
   System.out.println("El numero no se encontro");
}else{
   System.out.println("La posicion del numero fue: " + resultado);
}
```

Ya que cuando imprimes la posición en el `else` nuevamente estas buscando un elemento que en teoria ya encontraste.

Comment: Por cierto, te recomendaria usar nombres de variables mas significativos, porque i,j,x,z no dicen mucho, si utilizaras nombres como limInf, limSup, etc. Seria mucho mas legible